# How do I change the background color onclick on python using turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've been trying to get these colors to trigger with each click in the background using turtle. It would be great if someone could help me thank you in advance for your responses!

```
    import turtle
    import random


    f = turtle.pen()
    BG=turtle.Screen()
    colors = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green']
    BG.bgcolor("black")


    richard.pencolor("orange")
    richard.penup()

    def draw(x,y):
    richard.goto(x,y)
    richard.pendown()
    for x in range(360):
    richard.forward(200)
    richard.left(108)
    richard.forward(205)
    richard.left(108)
    richard.forward(210)
    richard.left(108)
    richard.forward(215)
    richard.left(1)
    richard.forward(220)
    richard.left(108)
    richard.forward(225)
    richard.left(108)
    richard.tilt(20)
    richard.speed(90)
    richard.pencolor()
    richard.pencolor(random.choice(colors))
    richard.bgcolor()
    richard.bgcolor(random.choice(colors))
    if(x % 2 ==1):
    richard.bgcolor(random.choice(colors))
    if(x % 2 ==1):
    richard.pencolor(random.choice(colors))
    richard.penup()
    BG.onclick(draw())
```

Comment: Your code indentation is messed up. Could you correct it ?

Comment: How? Could you please help me solve my problem?

Comment: Copy and paste your code properly as all the code indentation is broken here.

Comment: Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is this line:

```
BG.onclick(draw())
```

We need to pass the `draw` function itself to `onclick()`, not the `None` that `draw()` returns:

```
BG.onclick(draw)
```

A simple example that just changes the background color when the window is clicked:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

COLORS = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green']

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")

def draw(x, y):
    color = choice(COLORS)

    while color == screen.bgcolor():  # don't use same color twice in a row
        color = choice(COLORS)

    screen.bgcolor(color)

screen.onclick(draw)
screen.mainloop()
```